# test oauth/token in spring boot: No converter found for return value of type: DefaultOAuth2AccessToken

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I try to test my `oauth/token` endpoint. As of now I'm at the point where I desperately add and remove annotations all over my app.

If i run the application and run a cli command it works fine:

```
http --form -a client:secret POST localhost:8080/oauth/token grant_type=password username=peter@example.com password=password
```

However my test case returns a 500:

```
class OAuth2Test : ApiAwareTestCase() {

    @Test
    fun `a user can request a token`() {
        val response = mockMvc.perform(
            post("/oauth/token")
                .contentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8")
                .with(httpBasic("client","secret"))
                .param("grant_type", "password")
                .param("username", "admin")
                .param("password", "admin_password")
        ).andReturn().response

        val resultString = response.contentAsString
        assert(true)
    }

}
```

The base class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace=AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@SpringBootTest(classes = [CoreApplication::class, ClientService::class, SecurityConfig::class, AuthorizationServerConfig::class])
abstract class ApiAwareTestCase {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var clientRepository: ClientRepository

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var context: WebApplicationContext

    protected lateinit var mockMvc: MockMvc

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        clientRepository.saveAndFlush(Client("admin", "admin_password", true))
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .webAppContextSetup(context)
            .apply<DefaultMockMvcBuilder>(springSecurity())
        .build()
    }

    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        clientRepository.deleteAll()
        clientRepository.flush()
    }
}
```

I get the error:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter found for return value of type: class org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.DefaultOAuth2AccessToken
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:225) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:218) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:82) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:119) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:870) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978) [spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:881) [spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
```

I have no clue about the problem, because i just get the correct payload when I run the application.

My AuthServer:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
class AuthorizationServerConfig : AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter() {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var clientService: ClientService

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var authenticationManager: AuthenticationManager

    private val tokenTimeout = 3600

    private val clientId = "client"
    private val secret = "\$2a\$10\$sS9bjMhJ8jQb0tKoBrTgPu2fg8uUWCbiTy69ayBzEOM8KeLPrDa7u"

    @Bean
    fun passwordEncoder() = BCryptPasswordEncoder()

    override fun configure(endpoints: AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer) {
        endpoints
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
            .userDetailsService(clientService)
    }

    override fun configure(clients: ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer) {
        clients
            .inMemory()
            .withClient(clientId)
            .secret(secret)
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds(tokenTimeout)
            .scopes("read", "write")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
    }
}
```

My security:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
class SecurityConfig : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    @Bean
    override fun authenticationManager() = super.authenticationManager()!!



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me very, very long but I found out that @DataJpaTest was the root of all evil. It stripped away a lot of config, and one of those configs where the default message converter.

Sigh.

Comment: ...so spring boot is the root of all evil!! agree? p.s. in order to complete your answer - how did u fix that?

Comment: I just removed the DataJPATest annotation. One Problem with boot is that you'll never find a matching Stackoverflow answer, because the config is always slightly different.